# Dependent relationship in mapped types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define a type that matches the following objects:

```js
{
  foo: {
    a: 5,
    f: (x: number) => {}
  },
  bar: {
    a: "bar",
    f: (x: string) => {}
  },
  // ...
}
```

Specifically, I want the function `f` to take an argument of the same type as field `a`. I tried the following, but it looks like Typescript doesn't do unification of this sort, I'm getting `Cannot find name 'U'`:

```js
type Spec<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends {
    a: infer U,
    f: (x: U) => void
  } ? T[Key] : never;
}
```

I also tried this, but I'm getting `Type '"a"' cannot be used to index type 'T[Key]'.`:

```js
type Spec<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends {
    a: infer U,
    f: (x: T[Key]['a']) => void
  } ? T[Key] : never;
}
```

Is there a way to express such a relationship in mapped types like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another generic type for the sub-objects, and invoke that type inside the mapper:

```
type Obj<T> = {
  a: T,
  f: (x: T) => void
}
type Spec<T extends Record<string, { a: unknown, f: unknown }>> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends Obj<T[key]['a']> ? T[key] : never;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! The `extends Record<...>` check is pretty clever, I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

The type of f changes with the type of a. Then T should be the interface of { foo: number; bar: string }:

```js
type Spec<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  [key in keyof T]: {
      a: T[key];
      f: (x: T[key]) => void;
  };
};

interface SomeInterface {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
}

const spec: Spec<SomeInterface> = {
    foo: {
        a: 5,
        f: (x: number) => {}
    },
    bar: {
        a: "bar",
        f: (x: string) => {}
    },
    // ...
}
```